# How do I add an "offset" to LookAt?

Tags: unity, animation, rotation, third-person-view, inverse-kinematics

I have created a Third Person Controller.
The camera is behind the player:

[image]

I would like to make it so that the player aims at the mouse pointer position.

To do that, I use the following code to rotate the chest towards the position:

```
        var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos.z = 10; // Make sure to add some "depth" to the screen point 
        var aim = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
        Chest.LookAt(aim);
```

The hands do not perfectly straightly point forwards, so I need to add an "offset" to the LookAt.

I tried this approach:

```
var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
mousePos.z = 10; // Make sure to add some "depth" to the screen point 
var aim = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
aim += new Vector3(ChestAimCenterOffsetForLookatBecauseChestIsNotStraightForward, 0, 0);

Chest.LookAt(aim);
```

Of course I do all rotation patching in LateUpdate(). In Update(), it would simply be erased by the animation itself.

It does work, but when the model is rotated around the Y axis, something goes wrong: The offset is "wrong", it doesn't have the same effect.

This surprises me because all I do is rotate the entire model.

So I think this line is not correct:

```
aim += new Vector3(ChestAimCenterOffsetForLookatBecauseChestIsNotStraightForward, 0, 0);
```

Is this not the way to offset the LookAt results?

Comment: You should probably be adjusting bones or IK targets, not the mesh objects themselves.  However, it's hard to be sure without knowing how the model is rigged.

Comment: @JimU I have edited my posting and explained that the rig is perfectly fine and that the twist comes from the aim pose itself. In this aim pose, the chest is just rotated. Maybe I didn't understand you correctly?

Comment: Is the statement `Chest.LookAt(aim)` affecting the model at all?

Comment: Is the model rigged for [Inverse Kinematics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html)?

Comment: @JimU I wanted to aim using the Chest rotation only, I didn't want to use IK. And yes, Chest.LookAt(aim) does what it should, only it was a bit off. When I read your comment, I took a look at the Chest rotation, and I noticed that it was Y= -15. When I put Y = 0, the aim pos was EXACTELY straight forward. I will add all of this to my posting to make it clear to the reader. Thank you very much so far!

Comment: @JimU I have rewritten my question in order to explain everything better. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: From your first screenshot, it appears only the model's torso is visible. Why not simply rotate the entire model towards the target?

Aiming at a target 90 degrees from the model's facing only by rotating its chest will twist its spine 90 degrees. Ouch.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why you expect or desire the chest to point at the target.  If your intention is for the most natural looking aiming poses, your model will do more than just rotate its chest. For example, consider that you want to look at something 90 degrees to your left. You might turn your torso 5 degrees, your head 45 degrees and your eyes 40 degrees.

Using an IK-target can pose the body more realistically by distributing the rotation needed to aim at a target across the model's hips, chest, solders, elbows and wrists.

Comment: @JimU I'm currently trying to copy RE4 in order to learn how they did it, and they do it using Chest rotation. In RE4, the entire body does move, too, but only if the chest is rotated exceeding a certain range.

Comment: @JimU I have found the real problem, I think, I have re-written my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an easy-to-read way to offset the LookAt is required, then the following will work:

```
Chest.LookAt(aim);
Chest.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(ChestAimCenterOffsetBecauseHandsDontPointStraightForward.x, ChestAimCenterOffsetBecauseHandsDontPointStraightForward.y, ChestAimCenterOffsetBecauseHandsDontPointStraightForward.z);
```

According to DMGregory's lesson however this is a more elegant and thus preferred solution with only 1 setter:

```
Quaternion lookAt = Quaternion.LookRotation(aim - Chest.position);
Quaternion correction = Quaternion.Euler(ChestAimCenterOffset);

Chest.rotation = lookAt * correction;
```

ps: I'm now using a Vector3 instead because I noticed that the up-down also needs an offset.